# How to retrieve the GPS location via SMS

Tags: android, sms, gps, location, latitude-longitude

I made an Application that gives me the location of my Android phone.

Now I want to make a method that helps me to retrieve the GPS location of my phone (latitude longitude or the address if possible) with an SMS.

Exemple: phone number 558899.
I send an Sms with "get location" to 558899 an get a message back with the coordinates.

Comment: SMS seems like an insecure way to retrieve GPS data. What would stop any random person from sending an SMS to your phone with "get location" in the message and getting your exact location back? I would recommend using some sort of web service to share the GPS data where the data is only shared once you give permission for it to be shared with specific people.

Comment: Not every provider offers unlimited plan for web service usage (I managed to pay ~3 Eur for ~1 MB while NOT roaming... learned my lesson hard way). To workaround this security issue you can add some long password.

Comment: Yes, password, or you could also whitelist acceptable numbers to respond to

Comment: And not every provider offers unlimited texting. Be sure your users know that they may be charged 5-10 cents per query if they don't have a texting plan.

Comment: It is good to accept both SMS and GPRS/3G since it is a choice which one convinient and suitable like 3G can track in map but SMS can get location instantly. Unlimited plan can only be argue if he want to send the data periodically. This feature become practical used like WaveSecure apps. It only have a usage if the phone being stolen. I can get location, lock my phone or even sound alarm if I realize it is just stolen. Just I need to supply the PIN no in the SMS but don't forget to delete the sent SMS from sent item or change the PIN later. It is not only secure but also securing the phone!

Answer (score 3):

this may help:

<strike>"Capture" incoming SMS:
http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=95</strike>

Send SMS:
http://www.anddev.org/how_to_send_sms-t552.html

Edit: Dead link. I don't remember what exactly was in it, just like Google's cache and Internet Wayback Machine. Following link should have some info on topic:

http://lamiaamb.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/android-capture-an-incoming-sms/

Comment: @Im0rtality - first link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class. Pass it's `getFromLocation()` method the longitude and latitude and the maximal number of results you want to get returned. You'll get a `List` of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) objects.

Comment: i already did it,now i´am trying to send it as an SMS when requested.