# How to get latitude, longitude and address in android

Tags: java, android, sms, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve the GPS location via SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345535/how-to-retrieve-the-gps-location-via-sms)

I am making an android application that is going to act like this:
When a user types a text message containing for example "findmyphone" or anything like that (it will not respond to other normal text messages) to the phone that is running the application, the application will automatically respond to that number with latitude, longitude and the address of the phone that is running the application.

I also need a button for testing it. And once the user presses the "Test" button, the latitude, longitude and address will appear in 2 textboxes, latitude and longitude in one, and the address in the other one. Thanks SO much in advance! This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindAndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button Nextbutton1, Nextbutton2, TestLocationService;
TextView Cordinates, Adress, FindAndroid;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Nextbutton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Nextbutton1);
    Nextbutton1.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.Nextbutton1:
        setContentView(R.layout.setup);
        Nextbutton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Nextbutton2);
        Nextbutton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        TestLocationService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.TestLocationService);
        TestLocationService.setOnClickListener(this);
        break;
    case R.id.Nextbutton2:
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        break;
    case R.id.TestLocationService:
        break;
    }
}
    public Address getAddressForLocation(Context context, Location location) throws IOException {

        if (location == null) {
            return null;
        }
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        int maxResults = 1;

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults);

        if (addresses.size() == 1) {
            return addresses.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: "How can i do this as simple as possible?" you should pay someone to do this for you ... this is the simplest solution ...

Comment: what's the error or problem your having?  Anyone can copy and paste code for a smoke screen.

Comment: All i need is something to happen once a sms is received, and how to get the latitude, longitude and adress. So if i've lost my phone, and then i lend anothers phone and send a sms to that phone containing: "PhoneLocate" it responds with adress and cordinates of that phone. But only if the word is PhoneLocate or the one i have specified. I already have an application on the android market, but its made with the app inventor, and i want to make it in eclipse, but doesn't got that much experience in location. The applications name is: PhoneLocator.

Answer (score 0):

I will not give detailed instructions on anything because you can do a google search or search StackOverflow for most information that you need.

To get a location, you would use [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and invoke `requestLocationUpdates`. There are plenty of tutorials that explain how to do this.

To receive an sms, you would need a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) declared in your Manifest like the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
```

Within this receivery you would use the [`SmsMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) class to get the necessary info from the sms.

Then to send an sms back, you would use [`SmsManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) and invoke `sendTextMessage`.

**BUT**:
You really need to do the work on your own. It's also good to note that there are a TON of phone locator applications on the Market already, so this might not be a worthwile app for you to make.

And again, you can search stackoverflow or [Google](http://google.com) to find out how to do each thing that you're needing.

And if you haven't done any actual Android programming (since you said you used app inventor), then you need to look at the [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html)